# Joining together nodejs html5 and canvas

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas

I've got a very simple html5 game on one side. Opening the game's html file directly with my browser makes the game work just fine. On the other side, I have an html sever made with node.js that can serve html text normally (tags like < /br> < p> and so on).

But when I tell the server to display my game as html text priting the whole html file, the canvas fails to render (although the title does). So now I'm kind of lost on what's happening and why I'm not able to link those two things together. Here's a simplified version of my server's code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(index);
    res.end()
}).listen(7777);
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Should this work normally? Am I missing something?

It seems just as if the javascript was sent as plain text and the code was never actually executed.

Comment: Are your CSS and JS code embedded in the index.html?  Html canvas requires JS to issue drawing commands.  You might need to require('yourJS.js').

Comment: intro story is totally unnecessary :)

Comment: I'll remove it then... I always try to provide some background but maybe this was too much.

Comment: @markE yes, most of the javascript is embedded in the html, I'll try to do what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server serves only the index.html so if that page depends on any other resources it will fail to work as requests to CSS and JS files will fail. Try out e.g. this:

```
$ npm -g install simplehttpserver
$ simplehttpserver /path/to/your/folder
```

Then go with browser to

```
http://localhost:8000/index.html
```